# top right side of my film photos have some sort of light leaks

Tags: 35mm, slr, light-leaks, pentax-k1000

The right side of the image has some sort of obvious light leak I'm unsure what is causing it, e.g. the lens, the camera etc. I have checked for leaks and I don't think I found any.
The camera is a Pentax k1000 and the lens is a sigma lens.

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: Can you post a photo of the negative strip?  It will help to know if this is only in the frame or goes over into the perforations and rebate between frames.

Comment: the development house emailed me the scans I am yet to get the negatives back and may not be able to for a little while is there anything else I can do or any common issues it may be caused from to check out in the mean time?

Comment: Without seeing the negatives we're guessing, at best -- or giving solutions that would have worked on a 50+ year old folding camera but won't on a 35mm SLR.

Comment: Is it the same on other pictures?

Comment: all of the pictures on the roll look like that except on some of them the white area on the right is less visible

Answer (score 3):

Procure a tiny flashlight that will stay on. Place it inside the camera and close it up. Take it to a closet that can be made light-tight. Take a stool with you because you will be in there for maybe 15 minutes. It takes that long for your eyes to dark adapt. While sitting in the dark, examine the camera from all angles.
If the camera allows light to leak in, it will also allow light to leak out.
This technique works, so don't foo-foo it.

Comment: That's completely inapplicable to a 35mm SLR.  No room inside for the light.

Comment: How small does it need to be? https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/bullet/bullet-02-worlds-smallest-flashlight-even-smaller or maybe https://www.torchdirect.co.uk/key-ring-torches/xtar-led-key-ring-torch.html

Comment: foo-foo or pooh-pooh?

Answer (score 3):

It's not the lens, because the lens is on the other side of the shutter from the film. Any light leaking into the mirror box, whether from the lens or anywhere else on the front of the camera, will only illuminate the film for the (typically) split-second the shutter is open for each exposure.

Light leaks don't have to let much light in, because they leak continuously anytime the camera is exposed to light. Remember that the top right of the frame is on the lower left (as viewed from behind the camera) when the negative is inside the camera. So look at the seals around the back door on the lower left.

[image]

You can pick up 3 sets of pre-cut new seals for the K1000 for around $25 on [eBAY](https://www.ebay.com/itm/154591037131).

[image]

Instructions for how to remove the old seals and install the new ones can be found [here](http://aki-asahi.com/store/html/sp/seal/index.php)

Comment: There’s a good chance the leak is happening on the take up spool.

Answer (score 1):

There is more light leaking shown in the top right of the picture. This is the bottom left of the camera because the negative is recorded upside down and reversed left to right.

On the Pentax K1000, the film door latches on the left.

I suspect the lower light seals and/or the large seal at the hinge.

Not that it makes much difference, just replace all the seals. It is a reasonable job to do yourself. K1000 light seals are available from Aki-ashi [here](http://aki-asahi.com/store/html/sp/seal/index.php).